# Captaincasa framework: touchfieldnumeric - disable text input field

Tags: captaincasa

When we use the touchfieldnumeric on a mobile device and we do input using the keypad, the "text input field" sometimes gets focused and it forces the touch keyboard to pop up which is an undesired behaviour.

How do i prevent the mobile keyboard to pop up ?

Update: resolved in a update to the framework which allows disabling of the field.

Comment: `<input inputmode='none'>` should work for any framework for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked this with demos in the demo workplace - and cannot reproduce this behavior. I assume you refer to the text-field in the numeric-touch-popup which actually shows the value of the touch-input? This text-field is set to inputmode "none" on HTML-element level - so I 100% doubt that this is the reason...

Please check: is there another field in your dialog that is fosused by your application? Focusing a field will bring up the mobile device's virtual keyboard.

Comment: the issue is not reproducible on my phone, but it is reproducible on a proprietary android device running android 9 and webview version 69 (hehe). And actually i do not find the inputmode HTML-element attribute being set. This might help as it's being supported since webview 66 and above.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Let's give a try with disabling the field input. - Only disadvantage: the user cannot place the caret anymore, but for numeric input this is not a big issue... I will notify once we have created a corresponding update.

Comment: just published interim update 20231102_INT2 by Maven repository. Here you can explicitly set TOUCHFIELDNUMERIC-FIELDENABLED to value "false". - Would be great if you could test if this bypasses "your" problem.